# Linking a third model in EF CORE

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, ef-code-first

This is the EF CORE setup I have at the moment.

Telephone model

```
[ForeignKey("TelNoTypeID")]
public int? TelNoTypeID { get; set; }
public DropDown TelNoType { get; set; }
```

Person model

```
public ICollection<Telephone> TelephoneIDs { get; set; }
```

I've also tried using

```
public virtual ICollection<Telephone> TelephoneIDs { get; set; }
```

DropDown model

```
public int DropDownID { get; set; }
public string DisplayText { get; set; }
```

Person controller

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Details(int? id)
{
    var person = await _context.Persons
        .Include(p => p.Gender)
        .Include(p => p.Title)
        .Include(p => p.AddressIDs)
        .Include(p => p.TelephoneIDs)
        .SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.PersonID == id);
```

So a collection of Telephone numbers are stored against the Person model.

This brings back from the database and displays on the screen the numeric value from the field

```
Telephones.TelNoTypeID
```

The equivalent SQL to what I have is

```
select Telephones.TelNoTypeID from Person
inner join Telephones on Telephones.PersonID = Person.PersonID
```

I need to display the linked text value instead which is stored in

```
DropDown.displaytext
```

The equivalent SQL to what I need is

```
select DropDown.displaytext from Person
inner join Telephones on Telephones.PersonID = Person.PersonID
inner join DropDown on DropDown.DropDownID = Telephones.TelNoTypeID
```

I've tried using

```
.ThenInclude(p => p.<something>)
```

but the Dot notation just refers to the generic collection properties/methods, not back to my person, dropdown or telephone models

I've linked the Person model directly to the Dropdown model using and displaying the dropdown.displaytext with

Person model

```
[ForeignKey("GenderID")]
public int? GenderID { get; set; }
public virtual DropDown Gender { get; set; }
```

but despite putting the same code into telephone, it's not working

How can I link a third model (DropDown) to a second model (Telephone)?

Thanks

Comment: `.Include(p => p.Gender)` , why?  Is Gender another class/table? The same for Title etc.

Comment: Post the complete (but shortened) classes. What is p.AddressIDs ? And is DisplayText in Person or in DropDown?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I was trying to link to the DropDown model, turns out I needed to link to the property, so

```
    var person = await _context.Persons
        .Include(p => p.Gender)
        .Include(p => p.Title)
        .Include(p => p.AddressIDs)
        .Include(p => p.TelephoneIDs)
            .ThenInclude(p => p.TelNoType)
        //.Include("TelephoneIDs.TelNoType.DisplayText")
        .SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.PersonID == id);
```

I don't understand why, I'm presuming it's because the links already exist between the 3 models and the ThenInclude points to the exact property I'm trying to link with/to.